# When n can be replaced with x in limits

Tags: limits

Given a function $f$, I'm trying to figure out when $$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} f(n) = \lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} f(x)$$
but I can't. I want to do that, so that I can apply L'Hôpital's rule. Or can I apply it directly with $n$?

Here, $n$ is a natural number, and $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Can someone help me?

Comment: If you are thinking of $n$ as an integer then the answer depends on the function. You couldn't do this for $f(x) = \sin( \pi x)$. You can when $f$ is monotonic.

Comment: @Curiouserandcuriouser i think $n\to\infty$ should suggest taking a limit in $n\in\Bbb N$ while $x\in\Bbb R$ is meant.

Comment: $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} f(x)\ $ exists and is equal to $\ L\in\mathbb{R}\implies \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} f(n) =L.\ $

 But $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} f(n) =t\in\mathbb{R} $ does not imply that $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} f(x)\ $ exists.

Comment: If $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists then $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)$ exists as a special case $x\in\Bbb N$ and they are equal. But the existence of $n\to\infty$ does not imply that of $x\to\infty$, like @EthanBolker suggested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the limit of $f(x)$ as the real number $x$ goes to infinity exists (including if it's infinite), then necessarily the limit of $f(n)$ as the integer $n$ goes to infinity exists and is the same.

So if you have a limit over the integers, you can *always* reinterpret the expression as a limit over the real numbers, and if you get a conclusive answer to the real limit using whatever tools you have at your disposal, then that's also your answer for the integer limit.

However, some times the integer limit can exist without the real number limit existing. The classic example is the function $x\mapsto \sin(2\pi x)$. And some times neither limit exists, such as with $x\mapsto \sin(x)$. And in those cases reinterpreting won't help you much with determining whether the integer limit exists or what its value could be.